# Are there any advanced (e.g. bigram) autocomplete plugins for Vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

For my particular cases, Vim's autocomplete often isn't that smart. Is there a way to switch to e.g. a bigram model (which predicts based on the previous word), or something even better? Would it be hard to write it myself (supposing I know how to write / use a n-gram histogram in an external program)?

Comment: Do you use `<C-n>`/`<C-p>` or `<C-x><C-o>`? From my experience, Vim is smart enough to put my custom methods at the top of the completion menu, is that what you mean? You say "autocomplete" but Vim doesn't provide automatic completion: do you want a plugin that does?

Comment: Sorry, I do mean whatever `Ctrl+N` is. There's cases where context matters a lot. For example, I was repetitively adding the phrase "ContraintKinds," after "BangPatterns," -- it should have been smart enough to know that the word "ConstraintKinds" often follows "BangPatterns".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the most powerful autocomplete plugin for vim is [neocomplcache: https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache).

It has a lot of configuration option and it is easily extensible. It has word, snippet, filename, register and omni (syntax) completion. It's the most definitive solution I have found in vim, even if I know I should learn more about it to use more efficiently.